# Using differencing multiple times for making dataset stationary

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, preprocessing, forecasting

When I do differencing to my dataset I am having a lot of zeroes and it causes my prediction to go wrong. But when I use it multiple times, my dataset is having minus values but still, at least my predictions are not being so bad. Is it allowed? are there any bad consequences to use differencing in the same dataset multiple times? Thanks.

Comment: Yes to the bad consequences, search for overdifferencing.

Comment: @user2974951 you mean I can use it? but when I will use it too much it will be overdifferencing and I should look at consequences of this?

Comment: I am saying that you shouldn't difference arbitrarily, as this will often lead to overdifferencing, which is bad. This does really depend on what your goal is, if your plan is to input this series into a machine learning model (based on your tags), you may find that you do not need to difference it at all, because you may loose important information this way. Classical time series models work differently from machine learning models, they do not have the same assumptions.

Comment: @user2974951 i will use it for LSTM models. Because when i use single differencing, my prediction is being absolute flat because of "0" values that came from differencing. So will i lose important information with this way do you think?

Comment: Hard to tell exactly ow your LSTM model will behave, however I would try not to difference first.